# what should be data type and scope of variables in operator overloading?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand operator overloading in c++. My first question is that can we add two objects and store its value in a variable? I tried this but got an error that lx and ly are not defined in this scope. Secondly I want to dispaly the result after addition what command should I give to show results? If I add two objects can I mention data type as int as I mentioned in the following code?

```
class Rectangle
{

private:
int L;
int B;

public:
lx;
ly;
Rectangle()    //default constructor
{
    L = 2;
    B = 2;
}

Rectangle(int l,int b)      //parametrized constructor
{
    L = l;
    B = b;
}

int operator+ (Rectangle obj2)    //operator overloading
{

    lx = this->L + obj2.L;
    ly = this->B + obj2.B;
    return lx,ly;

}  

void Display()
{
    cout<< "length is " << L <<endl;
    cout<< "breadth is " << B <<endl;
}

};

int main()
{
Rectangle R1;
R1.Display();

Rectangle R2(5,3);
R2.Display();

return 0;



}
```

Comment: `return lx,ly` probably not what you think it does.

Comment: You forgot `int` before `lx` and before `ly` right after `public` in the class declaration

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? You haven't specified the type of the data members `lx` and `ly`.

Comment: yes it is compiling after mentioning dtype. But if I want to show the result after addition. How should I call that function?

Answer (score 2):

To store the results of the addition in member variables seems to make no sense. **You want to add two Rectangle objects, the return value should logically also be a Rectangle.**

This is a usual way to overload operator + and to print the result.

```
     #include <iostream>

    class Rectangle
    {
    private:
        int L;
        int B;

    public:
    //    int lx;
    //    int ly;

    Rectangle()    //default constructor
    {
        L = 2;
        B = 2;
    }

    Rectangle(int l,int b)      //parametrized constructor
    {
        L = l;
        B = b;
    }

    Rectangle operator+ (Rectangle obj2)    //operator overloading
    {
       Rectangle rec ( this->L + obj2.L, this->B + obj2.B);
       return rec;
    }
    void Display()
    {
        std::cout<< "length is " << L <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< "breadth is " << B <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle R1;
    R1.Display();

    Rectangle R2(5,3);
    R2.Display();

    Rectangle R3 = R1 + R2;
    R3.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is wrong

```
public:
lx;
ly;
```

you need to write:

```
public:
int lx;
int ly;
```

Then your overloaded `+` operator should return a `Rectangle` and not an `int`:

```
Rectangle operator+(const Rectangle & obj2)
{
  Rectangle result;
  result.L = L + obj2.L;
  result.B = B + obj2.B;
  return result;
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
Rectangle operator+(const Rectangle & obj2)
{
  Rectangle rec(L + obj2.L, B + obj2.B);
  return rec;
}
```

Or simplest:

```
Rectangle operator+(const Rectangle & obj2)
{
  return Rectangle(L + obj2.L, B + obj2.B);
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
Rectangle r3 = R1 + R2;
```

The `const` and the `+` in `operator+(const Rectangle & obj2)` are not strictly necessary, you could also write `operator+(Rectangle obj2)` as you did in your initial attempt.

Using the `&` is slighly more efficient because it prevents the argument from being copied and the `const` prevents the programmer from modifying the argument, which would modify the operand when using `&`.

Comment: You could also make the `operator+` a `const` member function since it doesn't modify `*this`.